# ¿Qué significa Single en un repositorio genérico de Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estoy utilizando un repositorio genérico, el patrón *repository* en el cual tengo este método.

```
 T Single(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
```

`T` es el tipo que le paso al patrón, me va a devolver una entidad, pero single que significa he buscado en internet y significa soltero, `bool` le paso un `true` o `false`, ¿`predicate` viene a ser un parámetro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El single no es soltero cuando se refiere a una entidad, sino a un dato unico.

El `predicate` es una expresion `lambda`

[Expresiones lambda (Guía de programación de C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-AR/library/bb397687.aspx)

El `true/false` indica que la expression lambda debe devolver un `bool`, debe ser una comparacion entre las propiedades de la entidad y algun valor que uses como filtro.

En este caso podria ser una expression que debe devolver un dato unico como ser

```
var result = repository.Single(x=> x.Id == 1);
```

con ese código indicas una expression que define un filtro que devolver ala entidad cuyo Id sea igual a un valor

Comment: IEnumerable<T> Filter(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        IEnumerable<T> Filter(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, List<Expression<Func<T, object>>> includes); Esto me estaria devolviendo una coleccion que diferencia hay entre estas dos.

Comment: exacto el Filter devuelve una lista de entidades que coincidan con el lambda que indiques como filtro. La diferencia es que en una devuelve la entidad que indicas, mientras que en el segudno puedes indicas si necesitas incluir alguna entidad relacionada. En el include defines las entidades de navegacion que quieres recuperar

Comment: Me refiero entre los dos IEnumerables por que con single estoy devolviendo la entidad.

Comment: no entendi el problema, los IEnumerables  son listas o colecciones, no son valores simples

Comment: Sería conveniente que ahondes más en la explicación de `Single` tal como se realiza en otras respuestas y evites colocar traducciones directas de un traductor p.e. *El single no es soltero(¿?)*

Comment: consulta a quien voto negativo, al menos podria explicar porque ? entiendo que la respuesta ayudo a quein realiza la pregunta, no es incorrecta y es mas explico lo de la expression lambda lo que no hace ningun de las otras respuestas, entonces al menos expliquense para poder mejorar, no voten negativo solo por el hecho que pueden hacerlo

Answer (score 2):

`Single` se refiere a que el método debe devolver un único resultado, ni más ni menos. Si el predicate se cumple para más elementos o para ninguno se espera que se lance una excepción.

Es así como funciona el método [`Single`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535118(v=vs.110).aspx) de LINQ y su semántica también es utilizada en LINQ to Entities.

Answer (score 2):

`Single` hacer que la consulta devuelva un solo elemento, y que lance una excepción **si no hay elementos** en la colección producto del predicado o si la consulta retorna **mas de un elemento**.

```
var entidad= base.Entidades
                   .Single(e => e.Id == idDeLoQueBusco);
```

Si hay no hay elementos o hay mas de 1 con el mismo Id, lanzara una excepción.

Por otro lado, tienes `SingleOrDefault()` que es igual, pero si no hay elementos en lugar de lanzar una excepción, retorna el valor por defecto para el tipo (generalmente null). De todos modos, este método lanzara una exception si la consulta retorna mas de un elemento.

Comment: Hola cuando llamo al método single desde la presentacion. seria Single(que va acá)?

Comment: Ya entendí, sorry

Answer (score 1):

El Single es tan simple como cuando buscas algo por su Id, como un método GetByID, donde pasas el ID puede ser de un cliente por ejemplo si encuentra Ese Id de un Cliente te devolverá ese cliente en particular, no te va a devolver ni dos ni tres, sino uno, el que tiene un ID en específico.